# Calling EJB3 from a Faces BackingBean

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0

I have a simple web application, packed as an EAR, deployed on Glassfish.
The EAR has a web module and an EJB module.
The web module has a faces page, and a ManagedBean.
The Faces page only has a button on it, and the button is tied to a method in the ManagedBean, and clicking the button does indeed fire the method.

The managed bean:

```
public class Bar {

    public Bar() {
    }

    @EJB StudentProfileFacade f;

    public void hello(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("*** f: " + f);
    }
}
```

The EJB is not getting injected, the error I get is:

```
Exception attempting to inject Unresolved Ejb-Ref com.web.Bar/f@jndi: com.StudentProfileFacade@null@com.StudentProfileFacade@Session@null into class com.web.Bar
```

What do I need to do so that the web module will find the EJB module, and the EJBs in it?

Comment: Does the EJB have a global JNDI name assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do jndi lookup instead of di. It could look like:

```
private StudentProfileFacadeInt getStudentProfileFacade() {
 try {
  InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
  return (StudentProfileFacadeInt) ctx.lookup("<application_name>/StudentProfileFacade/local");
 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new RuntimeException("couldn't lookup StudentProfileFacade", e);
 }
}
```

Where `StudentProfileFacadeInt` is a local interfejs for `StudentProfileFacade`.